# Add additional joins to already joined table in SQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have a existing query where I am using joins (thanks [RADAR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3950946/radar)) to get my data.

### Working SQL

```
SELECT
 IFNULL(f.field_full_name_value, 'No Value'), u.name, u.uid, n.title, n.nid, a.timestamp, d.field_video_duration_value AS duration
FROM
db_node_view_count a
join db_node n
ON a.nid = n.nid
JOIN db_field_data_field_video_duration d
ON n.nid = d.entity_id
JOIN db_users u
ON a.uid = u.uid
AND u.uid <> 1
LEFT JOIN db_field_data_field_full_name f 
ON u.uid = f.entity_id
ORDER BY u.uid desc
```

What I want to do is that I want to extend the query to show roles of a `db_users u`. There is a table called db_`roles`, which contain all role names with a primary key rid. Then the second table is `db_users_roles`, which contains a matching `uid` (from db_users u) and rid to show which user selected which role.

So what I did was that under `ON a.uid = u.uid`, I added `JOIN db_users_roles ur ON u.uid = ur.uid JOIN db_role r ON ur.rid = r.rid`. It works fine but it shows duplicate rows. Any idea why it's happening?

```
SELECT
 IFNULL(f.field_full_name_value, 'No Value'), r.name, u.name, u.uid, n.title, n.nid, a.timestamp, d.field_video_duration_value AS duration
FROM
db_node_view_count a
join db_node n
ON a.nid = n.nid
JOIN db_field_data_field_video_duration d
ON n.nid = d.entity_id
JOIN db_users u
ON a.uid = u.uid
LEFT JOIN db_users_roles ur
ON u.uid = ur.uid 
LEFT JOIN db_role r
ON ur.rid = r.rid 
AND u.uid <> 1
LEFT JOIN db_field_data_field_full_name f 
ON u.uid = f.entity_id
ORDER BY u.uid desc
```

### UPDATE

With help from Joe, here is a slight update:

```
SELECT
 IFNULL(f.field_full_name_value, 'No Value'), GROUP_CONCAT(r.name), u.name, u.uid, n.title, n.nid, a.timestamp, d.field_video_duration_value AS duration
FROM
db_node_view_count a
join db_node n
ON a.nid = n.nid
JOIN db_field_data_field_video_duration d
ON n.nid = d.entity_id
JOIN db_users u
ON a.uid = u.uid
LEFT JOIN db_users_roles ur
ON u.uid = ur.uid 
LEFT JOIN db_role r
ON ur.rid = r.rid 
AND u.uid <> 1
LEFT JOIN db_field_data_field_full_name f 
ON u.uid = f.entity_id
GROUP BY f.field_full_name_value
ORDER BY u.uid desc
```

Comment: any pointer, suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some users in your (Drupal) database may have more than one role. So where your original query had (simplified a bit) one row per node, the modified query will duplicate the rows for each role of the user.

You might want to modify the query to include 
GROUP BY n.nid, u.uid
and change the SELECT field list to include GROUP_CONCAT(r.name) rather than r.name.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thank you for your assistance. It did work exactly how I wanted it to be. Just one little issue. Although `GROUP_CONCAT` did work exactly how it should've worked for roles, yet I don't want to Group by User. I want to show each user's row with respect to their visit (the way it is in my query before your change). I updated the query as you suggested. Please take a look. I hope we could implement the Group_concat but don't have to group the user names. Thanks.